# How to handle unset/default dates in Laravel? (with Carbon)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Laravel automatically passes the `created_at` and the `updated_at` (from an Eloquent model) into a new Carbon instance, as per the documentation.

It seems though, that if the value is the default `0000-00-00 00:00:00` it outputs the following:
`-0001-11-30 06:12:32` for all `0000-00-00 00:00:00` values.

The fields are set to timestamp type.

I'm using the following at the moment (within the model), but it feels clumsy to have to do this across all Laravel models that may contain a default/unset date.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) {
    return $value == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ? "0000-00-00 00:00:00" : $value;
}
```

Comment: "it feels clumsy to have to do this across all Laravel models that may contain a default/unset date." you could put it in a BaseModel that extends Model, and have all your models extend the BaseModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no clean way to do this. So I went with:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) {
    return $value == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ? "0000-00-00 00:00:00" : $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening in the getAttributeValue method, in [model.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2107)

```
elseif (in_array($key, $this->getDates()))
    {
        if ($value) return $this->asDateTime($value);
    }
```

as it is being passed to the asDateTime method.
This could be fixed with something like

```
elseif (in_array($key, $this->getDates()))
    {
        if ($value && $value !== '0000-00-00 00:00:00') return $this->asDateTime($value);
    }
```

Could this be an issue for a pull request?

Comment: Hey, I don't really understand your answer but it's marked as correct. Are you just saying that Laravel 4 doesn't have a nice way for this and that @Chris's solution is the only available?

Comment: @MAuro Good point, I ended up going for the solution in my original question. So I will post that as an answer and mark it accepted